# Is it possible to find Hamilton path in this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I've been ask if there is any way to find an Hamilton path in this new Q4 [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5VII.png)

i think it's impossible because it isnt an even bipartite graph and not all the degs is even. is this true ?

Comment: No. The "even degrees" means it's *Eulerian*. And non-bipartite graphs (like $K_3$) can be Hamiltonian.

Comment: so beside trying to draw the path, there is any way to determinete if there is an hamilton path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- This graph is bipartite.
- If you color vertices black and white, then the difference between the counts has to be at most $1$ for the Hamilton path to exist.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$